# Question About Kissing Numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Soft question: Is there anything special about the dimensions for which a kissing number solution is known, namely $1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 24$? Intuition can solve the problem in dimensions $1, 2, 3$ and maybe $4$ but definitely not $8$ and $24$. All known solutions so far are divisors of $24$.

Is this a coincidence?

I know that solutions for $8$ and $24$ are due to the existence of lattices ($E_8$ and $\Lambda_{24}$); however, I feel as if this is an unsatisfying answer.

Why is it only in dimensions $8$ and $24$ that lattices exist for which a solution to the kissing problem can be found?

Comment: You can look in terms of "arrangement of spheres around a specific sphere is rigid" property, in which case the only known dimensions to satisfy that are 1,2,8,24. I think the question would be phrased better that way.

Comment: Interesting! I assume it is therefore easier to solve the kissing number if the arrangement is rigid. But, again (ignoring the dimensions in which the sphere packing problem is intuitive), why $8$ and $24$ dimensions?

Comment: I think the reason is basically just the existence of a highly symmetric lattice.

Comment: One dimension is trivial; two dimensions nearly so. Three dimensions took a while, and was not rigorously proved until the $20$th century. Musin proved the four-dimensional case using a clever extension of the Delsarte method, which he also applied to the three-dimensional case (just to show off). In the case of eight and $24$ dimensions, those were solved earlier because of the existence of the highly symmetrical $E_8$ and Leech lattices (as @mathlander alluded to).

Comment: But why do such lattices exist in $8$ and $24$? They kinda seem like random numbers. Is there some underlying structure that admits highly symmetric lattices in dimensions $8$ and $24$?

Comment: @MakoJ: I'm not aware of any *more primitive* attribute of $8$ and $24$ that would lend themselves to the existence of highly symmetric lattices—more primitive than the lattices themselves, in other words. ETA: $8$ and $24$ seem highly non-random to me—as $2^3$ and $4!$, for example—but Guy's strong law of small numbers probably applies. :-)

Comment: There might be something hiding in there, but we don't have enough examples to go from. It might be interesting if someday someone found some (say) $384$-dimensional lattice that solved the kissing number problem for that dimension. But two lattices isn't much to go on. In the meantime, the Delsarte method (extended by Musin) is quite powerful, but it requires the researcher to have identified a candidate best arrangement, and then the Delsarte-Musin method can be used to show that arrangement is optimal.

Comment: @BrianTung I have never heard of the Delsarte method before, it seems interesting. Thanks!

Comment: It's a coding theory thing. :-)

Comment: The fact that "especially good" lattices appear essentially in dimensions divisible by 8 might be construed as something about the associated theta series, and holomorphic modular forms... ?

Comment: One construction of the $E_8$-lattice relies on the existence of a very good self-dual binary code, namely the extended Hamming code. The Leech lattice is also related to the self-dual extended Golay code (an even more remarkable code). Self-duality is a very strong requirement for a binary code to have. Certain types of self-dual codes can only exist if the length (that translates to the dimension) is a multiple of $8$. Then, $16$ doesn't work nearly as well as $8$ and $24$, because those codes are not very good.

Comment: I'm sad to say I'm rusty with the details. But IIRC self-duality says something nice about the theta series, and doubly-even (or type II) self-dual codes with a good minimum distance are required for the resulting lattice to be any good. I apologize for being unable to say something intelligible. The early chapters of Conway & Sloane are a better source.

Comment: [Basic pieces about self-dual codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_code). My recollection was right, doubly-even can exist only when the length is a multiple of 8. The weight enumerators for such beasts are severely constrained by a theorem of Gleason. That may serve as a buzzword.

Comment: [A link to a paper from 1972](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1109/TIT.1972.1054817).

Comment: If you end up wanting a complete answer of the question you just deleted let me know.  The result is not new.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Yes please! I deleted it since I wasn't sure if it was new or not and thought to try again at proving it incase it was new

Comment: Well you should know that the identity was not entirely correct. You were missing a factor that fluctuates between positive and negative one. The relation can be derived from the functional equation of the zeta function, the reflection formula for the gamma function and the double angle formula for the sine function.